# How to upload high resolution image to folder using gd library or any method?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-uploading, gdlib

How to upload high resolution image to folder using gd library or any method? Any help appreciated.

```
    mkdir("../Connectors/upload_images/$album_name/");

    $file_tmpname=$_FILES['is_albimg']['tmp_name'];

    $file_name=$_FILES['is_albimg']['name'];

    $file_nm=explode('.',$file_name);

    //print_r($file_nm); die();

    $fname2=$file_nm[0].time().".".$file_nm[1];

    $hash = hash('md5', $fname2);

    $fname = $hash.".".$file_nm[1];

                $up='../Connectors/upload_images/'.$album_name.'/'.$fname;

    //echo $up; die();

    move_uploaded_file($file_tmpname,$up) or die();
```

Comment: What is the question? Where is the relation between handling an upload and gdlib?

Comment: i want to upload photo which is high and low resolution in image folder

Comment: Before it upload into image folder it will convert in two thumb which is high and low resolution thumb respective

Comment: @peter plz help me if you have any idea .......it's Urgent!!!!!

Comment: @user1999168 sorry, I'm not familiar with PHP at all - I just corrected the input.

Comment: It's better if you do a Google Search first. I did and it returns an SO post: [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347698/how-do-you-make-thumbnails-on-upload-with-phpthumb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP upload processing does not know anything about imges, much less about resolution. It just handles files.

If you want to create a scaled-down preview from an uploaded image (I gues that's what you want; your actual question is less than clear), get yourself familiar with GD, and create the image.

Check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Specifically, `imagecopyresampled()`.

Please note that the code sample posted here contains **grave security issues**; I hope that is just an example and not production code. Check out the PHP manual on handling uploaded files here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php